# How to obtain in R a good formula for glm (general linear models) to predict a binomial variable?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Is there a package or library that can help me suggest a formula given the independent variables which will work well in glm, for example this formula can be something like x^2+log(y)+Z, it does not necessarily need to be the standard linear model x+y+z in order to explain a variable.

Comment: @mariana, I don't understand. Both models you listed are linear in the coefficients. Are you looking for something that automatically does both feature extraction *and* model selection? Regards.

Comment: Yes, but mostly for model selection.

Comment: @Mariana Do you mean "general linear model" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model ) or "generalized linear model" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model )?  The second one handles binomial dependent variables.

Comment: I mean the R function called glm, which is actually the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model (general linear_model)

Comment: Actually, the glm function is for generalized linear models (logistic regression, Poisson regression, etc.). Of course, if you use glm with family=gaussian, then it is a general linear model, but in that case, one would just use the lm function.

Comment: Interesting comment, now I understand the difference is that one can use different distribussions and the other not, by the way I have been reading the material below and it might interest you. Thanks for the aclaration between the differences in glm and lm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest trying the [glmnet package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) for feature selection.  glmnet uses the [elastic net](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=6DD6392682DB8F43219A2C81171B64CF?doi=10.1.1.124.4696&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for regularization and feature selection, and is a pretty solid method for choosing a subset of variables for a glm.

If you want to automatically choose transformations for your dependent variable, I suggest checking out the [preProcess](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=caret%3apreProcess) function in the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) package.  preProcess can help you choose sensible transformations for both your dependent and independent variables.

So, preProcess will select transformations for you, such as log(y).  Then glmnet will select a sensible subset of your variables to build a model (i.e. not all of your independent variables may be important for your model).  You can use the cv.glmnet function to fine-tune the hyper-parameters.  I hope I've answered all your questions!

Comment: Your answer is excellent, now I understand so much more, I can not believe it. Let me tell you that I use to perform .s3 procedure transformation in all my analysis (at least I intuitively understood that. The process to take care of the variables before 5& or after 95% was called by a friend something like winzorize, but I tend to use it with a 2 percent margin (I guess it all depends on the variables you have).I am eager to  the other transformations using functions and else to see how it works.

Comment: Regarding the second package it seemed amazing to me, explaining al that methods for what is the best option for modifying the variables, let me tell you that at least I intuited several stuff of the things that are there, for example I use to eliminate dependent variables when some of them where highly correlated, which to eliminate was decided by my with different criteria such as first eliminating the variable less correlated with the dependent variable.   I really appreciate this, hope we keep in touch.

Comment: Elimination of variables in this way will result in major biases.  The approach is not driven by any statistical principles I can think of.  Use a principled approach, i.e., either pre-specify the model and use only methods blinded to Y (the response variable) to select the Xs, or use something like glmnet.  I don't see how Winsorization applies here either.  Variable selection without shrinkage (direct penalty for selection and estimation) is a disaster.  The original set of functions you specified for the predictor X's doesn't make as much sense as using spline bases, usually.

Comment: @Frank Harrell caret's feature selection routines include a cross-validation step which can be use to greatly reduce potential bias.  Also the preProcess step only removes highly correlated variables or variables with extremely low variance (which could cause problems during cross validation)

Comment: @mariana soffer I'm glad I could help you out! If you like my answer, feel free to 'accept' it by clicking the green check mark!

Comment: I have not used caret but it would have to incorporate penalization (shrinkage), not just cross-validation, to do the job.

Comment: @Frank Harrell the feature selection routines in caret are aimed at algorithms that do not have "built-in" feature selection. At the end of a feature selection run, you get a cross-validated variable importance measure, which you can then use yourself for shrinkage or selection.  You can read more about the process here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretSelection.pdf

Comment: Zach, do you how it goes with `glmnet` which uses its own internal CV loop for optimizing its penalty parameter?

Comment: @chl: I believe `caret` serves as a replacement for `glmnet`'s internal CV loop.  caret will only run one model per value of the `.alpha` parameter, as each model will return the entire regularization path up to the maximum value for `.lambda`.  It works similarly for `gbm` and other algorithms with their own cross validation procedures.

Comment: @Zach Thanks. My problem was with the choice of the penalty tuning grid. Apparently, Max Kuhn confirms [this is possible](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/303113.html), as you suggest.

Comment: @chl yeah, it's a pretty flexible package.  You can even pass a customer error function via the summaryFunction argument to traincontrol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  the [glmulti](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/index.html) package as well.

Comment: Hi @kc2112, welcome to the site. This contribution looks like it could have been posted as a comment. It's helpful to have a little more info in an answer. Would you care to say something about the pros & cons of `glmulti` vs. `glmnet` (which was already proposed). Do you like it better? Is it faster, or more stable, or just preferable under some circumstances but not others? etc.